# Matching Pipe Character in Java

Tags: java, regex

How should I match and replace Pipe character in Java? The following code tried to find and remove "|" from str and it doesn't work.

```
String str = "ABC | DEF | GHI";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\|");
Matcher m = p.matcher();
while (m.find()) {
    str = str.replaceAll(m.group(), "");
    str = str.trim();

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with good 'ol `String.replace`? No need for Regex here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char)

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers the problem seems to be that seeing the name when compared to `.replaceAll()`, people assume that `.replace()` will only replace the first occurrence... Which is not true, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) like so,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "ABC | DEF | GHI";
  System.out.println(str.replace(" | ", " "));
}
```

Output is

```
ABC DEF GHI
```

Comment: You're right but what I am trying to do is more complicated. I need to clean up some web page titles which are like: "fgdfgf sfgffg | fgd | fgf" and remove the "| fgd | fgf" part. But I can't even match the pipe character. I can do it with replaceAll("\\|") but using Pattern doesn't work. So I was wondering what is the difference?!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
str = pattern.matcher(str.replace("|", "")).replaceAll(" ").trim();
```

Note that `.trim()` will remove only beginning and trailing space characters/newlines from the input.

Comment: I guess you meant `str = pattern.matcher...`?

Comment: @donfuxx oops... Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
"ABC | DEF | GHI".replaceAll("\\s*\\|\\s*", " ");
```